# Значения из ячейки MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

Здравствуйте, помогите решить проблему, есть сайт с БД, при нажатии кнопки на сайте выводится полный текст из БД который указан на картинке, как сделать так что бы значения показывались по порядку ? к примеру нажал 1 раз и появился текст 123, нажал 2 раз и показывается текс 1234
Возможно ли это сделать ?

```
<?php

class ItemsKeys {
    public function add($data) {
        global $db, $me;
        set_lang_name('items');

        $query = $db->insert('items_keys', array(
            'key' => $data['key'],
            'date' => time(),
            'help' => $data['help'],
            'instruction' => $data['instruction'],
            'inform' => $data['inform'],
            'item_id' => $data['item_id'],
            'number' => $data['number']
        ));

        if ($query) {           
            $me->add_notification(__('Successfully added.'), 'success');
        } else {
            $me->add_notification(__('Not added.'), 'danger');
        }
    }

    public function save($arg) {
        global $db, $me;
        set_lang_name('items');

        $db->where('id', $arg['id']);

        $query = $db->update('items_keys', array(
            'key' => $arg['key'],
            'help' => $arg['help'],
            'instruction' => $arg['instruction'],
            'inform' => $arg['inform'],
            'item_id' => $arg['item_id'],
            'number' => $arg['number']
        ));

        if ($query) {
            $me->add_notification(__('Successfully saved.'), 'success');
        } else {
            $me->add_notification(__('Error saving.'), 'danger');
        }
    }

    public function delete($arg) {
        global $db, $me;
        set_lang_name('items');

        $db->where('id', $arg['id']);
        $query = $db->delete('items_keys');

        if ($query) {           
            $me->add_notification(__('Successfully removed.'), 'success');
        } else {
            $me->add_notification(__('Error removing.'), 'danger');
        }
    }

    public function get($arg) {     
        global $db, $me;

        if (isset($arg['id'])) {
            $db->where('id', $arg['id']);
        } elseif (isset($arg['item_id'])) {
            $db->where('item_id', $arg['item_id']);
        } else {
            return;
        }

        $query = $db->getOne('items_keys'); 
        if (!$query) return;
        if (!$query['key']) $query['key'] = '';
        if (!$query['help']) $query['help'] = '';
        if (!$query['instruction']) $query['instruction'] = '';
        if (!$query['inform']) $query['inform'] = '';
        if (!$query['item_id']) $query['item_id'] = '';

        return $query;
    }

    public function get_keys($num = 10) {   
        global $db;
        return $db->get('items_keys', $num);
    }

    public function get_sum_keys($id) {
        global $db;
        $db->where('item_id', $id);
        $query = $db->getOne('items_keys', 'sum(number), count(*) as sum');
        return $query['sum(number)'] ? $query['sum(number)'] : 0;
    }

    public function take_key($item_id) {
        global $db, $me;
        set_lang_name('items');

        // Item
        $user = $me->config('user');
        $item = Items::get($item_id);

        if (!$item) {
            $me->add_notification(__('Item not found.'), 'danger');
            return;
        } elseif (!$me->config('auth', false) || $item['cost'] > $user['points']) {
            $me->add_notification(__('Not enough points.'), 'danger');
            return;
        } elseif ($item['group_tasks_id']) {
            $result = ItemsTasks::verify_tasks($item['group_tasks_id']);
            if (!$result) {             
                $me->add_notification(__('Did not do all tasks.'), 'danger');
                return;
            }
        }

        // Key
        $key = ItemsKeys::get(array('item_id' => $item['id']));

        if (!$key || $key['number'] <= 0) {
            $me->add_notification(__('Key not found.'), 'danger');
            return;
        }

        // Update
        $user['points'] = $user['points'] - $item['cost'];
        $me->set_config('user', $user);

        $db->where('id', $user['id']);
        $query = $db->update('users', array(
            'points' => $user['points']
        ));

        if (!$query) {
            $me->add_notification(__('Unknown error.'), 'danger');
            return;
        }

        $db->where('id', $key['id']);
        $query1 = $db->update('items_keys', array(
            'number' => $db->dec()
        ));

        $db->where('id', $item['id']);
        $query2 = $db->update('items', array(
            'distributed' => $db->inc()
        ));

        if (!$query1 || !$query2) {
            $me->add_notification(__('Unknown error.'), 'danger');
            return;
        }

        if ($key['inform']) {
            Message::add(array(
                'user_id'   => 0,
                'sender_id' => 0,
                'subject'   => 'Key',
                'text'      => "User ID: ".$user['id']."\n\n".
                               "Item ID:\n".$item['id']."\n".
                               "Group tasks ID:\n".$item['group_tasks_id']."\n\n".
                               "Key ID:\n".$key['id']."\n".
                               "Key:\n".$key['key']
            ));
        }

        // Result
        $result = array();
        $result['item'] = $item;
        $result['key'] = $key;

        return $result;
    }
}

$me->add_interface('items', 'add_key', array('ItemsKeys', 'add'), 10);
$me->add_interface('items', 'save_key', array('ItemsKeys', 'save'), 10);
$me->add_interface('items', 'delete_key', array('ItemsKeys', 'delete'), 10);
$me->add_interface('items', 'get_key', array('ItemsKeys', 'get'));
$me->add_interface('items', 'get_keys', array('ItemsKeys', 'get_keys'));
$me->add_interface('items', 'get_sum_keys', array('ItemsKeys', 'get_sum_keys'));
$me->add_interface('items', 'take_key', array('ItemsKeys', 'take_key'), 1);

?>
```

Comment: Приведите текст исходного кода или запросов. Также приведите структуры таблиц, если это требуется. Никто глядя на картинку не сможет сказать что именно скрывается за GUI.

Comment: в самой БД возможно как то прописать значения что бы они по порядку выводились ?

Comment: Каким образом сайт обрабатывает запросы к бд?

Comment: обновил первый пост

Comment: Порядок вывода может определить или SELECT на T-SQL в БД или некий Controller (в вашем случае написанный на языке PHP). Если используется паттерн MVC, то сортировку можно сделать на нескольких уровнях. В зависимости от принятой архитектуры и подходов.

Comment: order by сортировать, limit ограничение